# finding character on dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a list of names. As of now, my code is able to add one name at a time. I want to identify if there is a comma (,) on my input, so I can add add that second or third name and create an individual `<li>`, how can I identify if an input has a specific character?

```js
var button;
var list = document.getElementById("greatList");
var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
//console.log(item);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init(){
  button = document.getElementById('addButton');
 

 document.querySelector('#addButton').addEventListener(addField);
 //button.addEventListener('click', getItem)

}

function addField(){
 var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
 var newField = document.createElement('li');
 newField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
 list.appendChild(newField);
 
}

function extraInput(){
 var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
 if (item.search(',') !== -1){
  console.log(true);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="list">
  <h2>List: </h2>
  <section class="top">

   <input type="text"  multiple="multiple" id="addItems">
   <button type="submit" id="addButton" onclick="addField()">Add</button>
   <button>Get Random</button>
  </section>
  <hr>
  <section class="result">
   <ul id="greatList">
    <li class="singleLine">Hello</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.split` function. Working code below.

```js
var button;
var list = document.getElementById("greatList");
var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
//console.log(item);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
  button = document.getElementById('addButton');
  document.querySelector('#addButton').addEventListener(addField);
  //button.addEventListener('click', getItem)

}

function addField() {
  var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
  if (item == "") {
    alert("enter something");
    return false;
  }
  var items = item.split(',');
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var newField = document.createElement('li');
    newField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[i]));
    list.appendChild(newField);
  }
}

function extraInput() {
  var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
  if (item.search(',') !== -1) {
    console.log(true);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <h2>List: </h2>
    <section class="top">

      <input type="text" multiple="multiple" id="addItems">
      <button type="submit" id="addButton" onclick="addField()">Add</button>
      <button>Get Random</button>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section class="result">
      <ul id="greatList">
        <li class="singleLine">Hello</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: I didnt f5 to know it already answered. just ignore it.**

```js
var button;
var list = document.getElementById("greatList");
var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
//console.log(item);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init(){
  button = document.getElementById('addButton');
 

 document.querySelector('#addButton').addEventListener(addField);
 //button.addEventListener('click', getItem)

}

function addField(){
     var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
if(isValid(item )){
var itemArr = item.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < itemArr.length; i++) {
  element = itemArr[i];
 var newField = document.createElement('li');
     newField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element ));
     list.appendChild(newField);
}
         
     }
else{alert('invalid text!');}
    }
function isValid(str){
 return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}
function extraInput(){
 var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value;
 if (item.search(',') !== -1){
  console.log(true);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="list">
  <h2>List: </h2>
  <section class="top">

   <input type="text"  multiple="multiple" id="addItems">
   <button type="submit" id="addButton" onclick="addField()">Add</button>
   <button>Get Random</button>
  </section>
  <hr>
  <section class="result">
   <ul id="greatList">
    <li class="singleLine">Hello</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try improve your function addField

```js
function addField(){
    var item = document.getElementById("addItems").value; //Get the string
    var res = item.split(","); //split the string and create an array
    res.forEach(function (value) { createField(value); }); //for each element in the array call to createField
    
 
}
function createField(text){
 var list = document.getElementById("greatList"); // use local variable, not global
 var newField = document.createElement('li');
 newField.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
 list.appendChild(newField);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="list">
  <h2>List: </h2>
  <section class="top">

   <input type="text"  multiple="multiple" id="addItems">
   <button type="submit" id="addButton" onclick="addField()">Add</button>
   <button>Get Random</button>
  </section>
  <hr>
  <section class="result">
   <ul id="greatList">
    <li class="singleLine">Hello</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```